# Highlight link in sidebar based on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, navbar

I'm building a sidebar nav that tracks where you are on the site. I have a drop down menu that expands when you hover on it. I want the link in the navbar to highlight to indicate which page you are on. I have it working for the parent pages, but if you hover on the dropdown and select a child link, then that link does not highlight and does not auto expand the menu to show you you're on that page.

I put my code in JSfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/6wrn5hgg/2/

Here is a quick glimpse at the code I'm using.

```
//Highlight current page
$(function() {
  $('a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
      $(this).addClass('current');
    }
  });
});

//subbar menu drop down
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('li.parent').hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings().find('.subnav').slideUp();
    $(this).children('.subnav').slideDown();

    if ($(this).children('.subnav').slideDown() == window.location.href) {
      $(this).addClass('current').slideDown();
    }
  });

});
```

How can I make the menu display the red background with the nav auto expanded?

Comment: Your all `<a >` tag has href `#` only.

Comment: I just did that becuase I didn't have anywhere to link it to in jsfiddle. Would it need actual links for it to work?

Comment: window.location.href would give you absolute paths. So you either needs to put the absolute path as href or you need to find the index of the href in window.location.href. Here's an example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/6wrn5hgg/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve what you are looking for, here's the options:

**Option 1: Use absolute url :**

Check if the value of `window.location.href` is exactly the same as the value of `href` of the `anchor` tag.

```
<li class="parent"><a href="https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/" class="">About Us <span class="caret"></span></a>  // with absolute url 

    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('.parent a').each(function() {
        if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
           $(this).addClass('current');
           $(this).closest('.parent').find('ul.subnav').slideDown();
        }
      });

      $('li.parent').hover(function() {
        $(this).siblings().find('.subnav').slideUp();
        $(this).children('.subnav').slideDown();

        if ($(this).children('.subnav').slideDown() == window.location.href) {
          $(this).addClass('current').slideDown();
        }
      });

    });
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/6wrn5hgg/4/

**Option 2 : Use relative url :**

Check if the value of `window.location.href` contains the value of `href` of the `anchor` tag.

```
<li class="parent"><a href="/_display/" class="">About Us <span class="caret"></span></a>  // with relative url



$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.parent a').each(function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf($(this).prop('href')) != -1) {
       $(this).addClass('current');
       $(this).closest('.parent').find('ul.subnav').slideDown();
    }
  });

  $('li.parent').hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings().find('.subnav').slideUp();
    $(this).children('.subnav').slideDown();

    if ($(this).children('.subnav').slideDown() == window.location.href) {
      $(this).addClass('current').slideDown();
    }
  });

});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/6wrn5hgg/5/

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! My paths are relative so I'm using option 2. The nav bar auto expands now, but it's not highlighting the link. Any ideas?

Comment: Check console.log($(this).prop('href')) and console.log(window.location.href) and check if the 2nd log value contains the 1st log value.

Comment: The first console.log says undefined. But the second one is giving me the entire URL

Comment: what is the value of the href in the a tag ?

Comment: You have absolute path for href, not relative . 'http://dev.peakalarm.com/peakav/'

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href` and `<a>` tag's `href` are not exactly same. Use `indexOf()` function instead.

```
$('.parent > a').each(function() {
   if (window.location.href.indexOf(this.href) > -1) {
       $(this).addClass('current');
   }
});
```

Comment: Add the html as well to your answer to understand the concept of indexOf for OP to understand.

Comment: In that case, you solution is not going to work because he has href = "#" whose index is -1 in window.location.href

Comment: Go through the comments of the question. He said this is only for the fiddle. In his original code he has actual `href`. @DinoMyte